# How to spoof the root of links to be a subdirectory? .htaccess

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess

I host quite a few websites on my server and they are all located in /var/www/. They are named after there domain e.g "website.com" would be located in /var/www/website.com/

The thing I need to be able to do is edit these websites without affecting the live version.

My idea was to use my servers IP as a sort of beta editing area. Let's say 123.123.123.123 is my servers IP. I want to be able to simply copy any of the live sites in to the 123.123.123.123/beta/ area and have all the links still work as normal.

Unfortunately some of the links are like this "/assets/images/etc...",

Is there a way to set the "/" to be the website's directory inside "beta" - e.g 123.123.123.123/beta/website.com/ instead of it looking in the real "/" - 123.123.123.123/

Needs to work with multiple websites in the "beta section".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a subdirectory, I recommend you either:

- Use a different domain (e.g. dev.example.com for the development or staging environment of www.example.com). Then you configure a virtual host for each of these domains which point to a copy of the site.
- Move your current web server (Apache, etc.) to a different port. Add a second web server, on the same box, but another port, and a reverse proxy (e.g. [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)), on the regular http/https port(s), with a cookie detection to send to either the dev or production environments. You then need a very small script to set or remove said cookie to switch from one environment to the other.

The latter option is a bit more complex to set up, but has quite a few advantages:
- you have a completely separate HTTP server, so you can even play with its settings without breaking anything in production
- you use exactly the same URLs in development/staging and production
- if you choose ports > 1000, you can even run your HTTP server as a regular user rather than root, so you can even restart it without going su/sudo. Drawback is that you can't use different users for different sites.

In both cases, don't forget to also make a copy of the database(s), and correctly point each environment to the right database(s). You probably want this to be automatic to avoid having to change config files between development/staging and production.

Note that you'll probably ultimately need more than 2 environments. Development, staging and production are good candidates.

Of course, you'll want to use source control (e.g. git) to keep track of changes and reflect them in production.

Comment: This sounds great! Thanks! I'll probably try to set up some sort of git, although is the method I was originally thinking of completely impossible to do?

Comment: If the page contains a link that looks like `/this`, there's no way to make the browser think that it should be asking for `/beta/this`, no. But if you're using either of the methods above you'll get the same practical effect. The first one is real easy to set up. If it's only for you, you could even edit your local `/etc/hosts` instead of editing DNS.